# Convertir DbSet<T> a tipo de dato diferente en EF - Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, linq-to-sql

Estoy trabajando en una expresión `Linq` en la cual obtengo un objeto de un `DBContext`, y quiero convertirlo en un objeto de un `ViewModel`

Mi `ViewModel` recibe como parámetro un objeto obtenido del `DBContext` para trabajar la información y retornarlo completo

```
public class Obj1 // Objeto obtenido de la base de datos
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public string Param { get; set; }
   public string Param2 { get; set; }
   public string Random { get; set; }
}

public class Obj2 //ViewModel
{
   public string ParamFormateado { get; set; }
   public string  Random { get; set; }

   public Obj2(Obj1 parametro)
   {
     ParamFormateado = parametro.Param + parametro.Param2;
     Random = parametro.Random;
   }

}
```

En esencia, la segunda clase trabaja sobre los parámetros de la primera y los formatea para después pasar a una vista.

Lo que intento hacer, es obtener un `Obj2` desde una base desde un `DBContext` que posee `Obj1`

Intento algo como esto

```
Obj2 objeto = db.Obj1.Where(x => x.id == "0").Select(x => new Obj2(x)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Es posible realizar una consulta `Linq` similar a la que planteo? ya que de otra manera, termino teniendo expresiones `Linq` sumamente largas para formatear esta información, sino, cual sería la mejor alternativa en estos casos?

Saludos y gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En stackoverflow en inglés una [Tim Schmelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284240/tim-schmelter) contestó mi [**pregunta**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51063061/linq-to-get-other-type-of-object-with-constructor/51063149#51063149), traduzco su respuesta para que pueda serle útil a otras personas.

> No puedes hacerlo, ya que sólo soporta constructores sin parámetros,
>   pero puedes hacerlo con `Linq-To-Objects`, que puede ser forzado con
>   [AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> ```
> Obj2 objeto = db.Obj1
>    .Where(x => x.id == "0")
>    .AsEnumerable()   // <--- here
>    .Select(x => new Obj2(x))
>    .FirstOrDefault();
> ```
>
> Por ende, el `Where` será ejecutado en la base de datos, pero el
>   resto, será ejecutado con `Linq-To-Objects`
>
> Para más información, pueden ver [este post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/14/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-36-asenumerable/) en el blog de **Jon
>   Skeet**

Comment: No es necesario que pongas _Solucionado_. Simplemente acepta tu respuesta. Debes esperar 48h para hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario ejecutar `Where` y luego `FirstOrDefault` para obtener el primer elemento recorriendo la coleccion

Para eso ejecuta `FirstOrDefault` y pasa la condición en este método directamente

```
Obj2 objeto = db.Obj1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == "0").Select(x => new Obj2(x));
```

Saludos